# Specifying lower half of a cube?

Tags: graphics3d

What's an easiest way to specify lower "half-cube" Graphics3D in Mathematica?

Using `RegionPlot3D` is easy but gives low quality graphics for cube (great quality for spheres however). An approach by specifying faces manually for a Polyhedron is below, but error prone....it ends up specifying the **upper** half-cube

```
Clear["Global`*"];

dvis = 2; (* vis dimension *)
d = 3; (* true dimension *)

norm2[vec_] = Total[vec*vec];

(* vec1,vec2 determine the plane of our section *)
vec1 = {1}~Join~ConstantArray[0, d - 1];
vec2 = Normalize[{0}~Join~ConstantArray[1, d - 1]];
mat = {vec1, vec2};

as = ConstantArray[a, d - 1];
zeros = 0*as;
zeros = ConstantArray[0, d];
a = 1;

(* Radius of inscribed sphere *)
R = a (Sqrt[d] - 1);

a = 1;

vec1 = {1}~Join~ConstantArray[0, d - 1];
vec2 = Normalize[{0}~Join~ConstantArray[1, d - 1]];
mat = {vec1, vec2};

normal = Cross @@ mat;
cornerSpheres = sphere[#, a] & /@ {c1, c2, c3, c4};
centerSphere = sphere[zeros, R];

halfCube = 
  Graphics3D@
   Polyhedron[{{-2, -2, -2}, {2, -2, -2}, {2, -2, 2}, {-2, -2, 2}, {2,
       2, 2}, {-2, 2, 2}}, {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 6, 5}, {1, 2, 5, 
      6}, {2, 3, 5}, {1, 4, 6}}];

c1 = {-a}~Join~as;
c2 = {a}~Join~as;
c3 = {-a}~Join~(-as);
c4 = {a}~Join~(-as);

c5 = {a, a, -a};
c6 = {-a, a, -a};

sphere[center_, radius_] := norm2[{x, y} . mat - center] <= radius^2;
cornerSpheres = Sphere[#, a] & /@ {c1, c2, c3, c4};
sideSpheres = Sphere[#, a] & /@ {c5};
centerSphere = Sphere[zeros, R];

regionPlot = 
  Graphics3D[
   cornerSpheres~Join~{Opacity[1]}~Join~sideSpheres~
    Join~{Opacity[1], \!\(\*
TagBox[
StyleBox[
RowBox[{"RGBColor", "[", 
RowBox[{"0.57`", ",", "0.54`", ",", "1"}], "]"}],
ShowSpecialCharacters->False,
ShowStringCharacters->True,
NumberMarks->True],
FullForm]\), centerSphere}];
Show[regionPlot, halfCube, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]
```

[image]

Comment: You could just flip the signs of all the $z$-coordinates of the vertices in your description of the half cube, right? No need to touch the list of faces of the polyhedron at all!

Comment: Maybe `Prism[{{-1, -1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}}]`

Comment: That is true. I had an easier time specifying half cube in terms of equations, but couldn't get region plot or discretize region to give me the high quality results

Comment: also `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion @ RegionIntersection[HalfSpace[{0, -1, 1}, 0], Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}]]`?

Comment: ... and `Graphics3D@ RegionProduct[Line[{{0}, {1}}], Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summarizing for posterity. The `RegionProduct` approach appears to be the most intuitive way.

```
Clear["Global`*"];

d = 3; (* true dimension *)
zeros = ConstantArray[0, d];
a = 1;

halfCube1 = 
     Polyhedron[{{-2, -2, -2}, {2, -2, -2}, {2, -2, 2}, {-2, -2, 
     2}, {2,
            2, 2}, {-2, 2, 2}}, {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 6, 5}, {1, 2, 5, 
           6}, {2, 3, 5}, {1, 4, 6}}];

bounds = {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}};
region = 
  RegionIntersection[HalfSpace[{0, -1, 1}, 0], 
   Cuboid[{-2, -2, -2}, {2, 2, 2}]];
halfCube2 = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[region, bounds];

halfCube3 = 
  Prism[{{-2, -2, -2}, {-2, 2, -2}, {-2, 2, 2}, {2, -2, -2}, {2, 
     2, -2}, {2, 2, 2}}];

halfCube4 = 
  RegionProduct[Line[{{-2}, {2}}], 
   Triangle[{{-2, -2}, {2, -2}, {2, 2}}]];

(* Radius of inscribed sphere *)
R = Sqrt[d] - 1;


as = ConstantArray[a, d - 1];
c1 = {-a}~Join~as;
c2 = {a}~Join~as;
c3 = {-a}~Join~(-as);
c4 = {a}~Join~(-as);

c5 = {a, a, -a};
c6 = {-a, a, -a};

cornerSpheres = Sphere[#, a] & /@ {c1, c2, c3, c4};
sideSpheres = Sphere[#, a] & /@ {c5};
centerSphere = Sphere[zeros, R];
blue = \!\(\*
TagBox[
StyleBox[
RowBox[{"RGBColor", "[", 
RowBox[{"0.57`", ",", "0.54`", ",", "1"}], "]"}],
ShowSpecialCharacters->False,
ShowStringCharacters->True,
NumberMarks->True],
FullForm]\);
spheres = cornerSpheres~Join~{Opacity[1]}~Join~sideSpheres~
       Join~{Opacity[1], blue, centerSphere};

data = {{halfCube1, "original"}, {halfCube2, 
    "BoundaryDiscretizeRegion"}, {halfCube3, "Prism"}, {halfCube4, 
    "RegionProduct"}};
Show[Graphics3D@spheres, Graphics3D@#[[1]], PlotRange -> bounds, 
   PlotLabel -> #[[2]]] & /@ data
```

[image]